# Distance between two places based on geolocation

Tags: soql, geolocation

I am trying to write a query to find contacts within a radius of 50 miles and here is the SOQL i have

```
select Id,Name,mailingStreet,mailingState,mailingCity,mailingPostalCode,mailingcountry,Mailing_Address_Latitude__c,Mailing_Address_Longitude__c,Mailing_Address_Accuracy__c FROM Contact 
                        WHERE 

                        distance(MailingAddress, geolocation(30.2672, 97.7431), 'mi') < 50 
                        ORDER BY distance(MailingAddress, geolocation(30.2672, 97.7431), 'mi'),mailingCity
                        LIMIT 20];
```

For some reason i dont get any records even though there are no of contacts with mailing address nearby.

I also created a formula field just to see what what i am getting on the distance. Here is the formula

```
DISTANCE( GEOLOCATION( Mailing_Address_Latitude__c , Mailing_Address_Longitude__c ), GEOLOCATION( Random_office__Latitude__s , Random_office__Longitude__s ) , 'mi')
```

The coordinates given in SOQL/formula are of austin.

All the values in the field came out to be > 6000. I thought distance should in miles, but doesnt seem to be logically correct.

I verified 2 addresses in googlemap and its distance was around 7 miles.

Can anyone let know what units the distance method return in? Or what am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are missing a `-` on the east/west coordinates?

> 30.2672, 97.7431 is somewhere in China
>
> 30.2672, -97.7431 is in Austin

Comment: Gosh!! time for coffee

Answer (score 1):

The latitude and longitude are both in degrees. If altitude is included, it is measured in meters. Ref: [Finding your position with Geolocation](http://html5doctor.com/finding-your-position-with-geolocation/).